# TAnchors() assignment in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder

I am using C++Builder XE4 VCL 32bit platform with Windows 7.

The assignment to the TAnchors() seen below is generating the warning: "W8084 Suggest parentheses to clarify precedence." Can you show how to adjust this assignment so no warning is generated. Thanks.

```
Edit7->Anchors = TAnchors() << akLeft >> akTop >> akRight >> akBottom;
```

Comment: Did you mean `TAnchors() << akLeft << akTop << akRight << akBottom;` ? (If not then can you explain what you are trying to do)

Comment: Calling the `TAnchors()` constructor creates a new `TAnchors` object that is empty.  It does not make sense to then use the `>>` operator to *remove* values that did not already exist in the first place.  This kind of code should only be using the `<<` operator to *add* values.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the round brackets below like this `(TAnchors() << akLeft)` seem to be the answer. This removes the warning.

---

```
Edit7->Anchors = (TAnchors() << akLeft) >> akTop >> akRight >> akBottom;
```

---